# Trying to identify this switch used in a toy vacuum cleaner

Tags: switches, identification

Hello electronics community,
Can you please help me identify this switch used in my kids vacuum cleaner toy? It is supposed to have a latch action (on after first press, off after subsequent press) but at the moment is is only on when maintained in the depressed position.
The back is glued but from what i can see it has two metal tabs on which the wires are soldered.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/APEM%20Components%20PDFs/MHPS_Series.pdf) are some similar switches. Measure the dimensions carefully (preferably with calipers) and compare those with datasheets from similar switches from a distributor such as Digikey or Mouser.

If you find one that is close enough you can order a replacement.